# How to remove StripedFly malware from Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: security, malware

I was reading [this](https://www.it-connect.fr/malware-stripedfly-1-million-pc-windows-linux-infectes/) article, and decided to search for sd-pam in the processes of one of my laptops.

I did `ps -x | grep -i "sd-pam"`, and got

```
2864 ?        S      0:00 (sd-pam)
29172 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto -i sd-pam
```

So I think I've got infected with this malware somehow. The laptop is old, and I remember during covid times my camera working without being user-activated (light was on), but I could never find out why.

I'm not an expert, nor even an experienced user/cybersecurity guy.

Is there something official by Ubuntu, to solve this?

PS: the article is in french. Here's also an [article in english](https://www.zetter-zeroday.com/p/sophisticated-stripedfly-spy-platform).

Comment: `sd-pam` also appears to be the name of a legitimate process forked by the systemd user slice (see `man user@.service` for example)

Comment: If you truly believe that you have a system infected with malware, then wipe-and-reinstall immediately. Malware worthy of a nickname can be hard to locate and even harder to eradicate. Restore your data from pre-infection backups, or you may re-compromise the newly-installed system. If you have been using an infected system for months (a camera light is NOT sufficient proof of infection), then that means sacrificing a lot of data; the consequence of delay. If you are unsure if your system is infected, then ask a question about how to find out.

Comment: @user535733 that's some valuable advice. Thanks ;)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks for the comment ;)